# AVAudioSession is playing ontop of the system sounds

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Hey so I have this code below. I am just trying to get it so that if their is any music, podcasts, etc is playing from another app inside of the OS that all sounds are muted.  However I have tried setting its category, and it won't work!  Am I not using the right category? Perhaps not in the right place?

The goal is that the user can listen to their own tunes while using the app.

```
sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GameMusic9", ofType: "mp3")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GameMusicRP", ofType: "mp3")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Death", ofType: "mp3")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tap", ofType: "wav")!)!)

        //Monsters
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blue", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Brown", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Green", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Orange", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Purple", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Red", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tan", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Yellow", ofType: "wav")!)!)
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Correct", ofType: "wav")!)!)//12
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Cowbell", ofType: "aiff")!)!)//13
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("12", ofType: "wav")!)!)//14
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Hybrid", ofType: "mp3")!)!)//15
        sounds.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Correct", ofType: "wav")!)!)//16

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)

        //Close or punch, or bycycle

        var error:NSError?
        for var i:Int = 0; i < sounds.count; i++
        {
            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sounds[i], error: &error))

            audioPlayers.last?.prepareToPlay()
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not using the right category. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories):

> `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`
>
> The category for an app in which sound
>   playback is nonprimary—that is, your app can be used successfully with
>   the sound turned off.
>
> This category is also appropriate for “play along” style apps, such as
>   a virtual piano that a user plays while the Music app is playing. When
>   you use this category, **audio from other apps mixes with your audio**.
>   Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch
>   (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone).

Try `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`:

> `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`
>
> The category for playing recorded music or other sounds that are
>   central to the successful use of your app.
>
> When using this category, your app audio continues with the Silent
>   switch set to silent or when the screen locks. (The switch is called
>   the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone.) To continue playing audio when your
>   app transitions to the background (for example, when the screen
>   locks), add the audio value to the UIBackgroundModes key in your
>   information property list file.
>
> By default, **using this category implies that your app’s audio is
>   nonmixable—activating your session will interrupt any other audio
>   sessions which are also nonmixable.** To allow mixing for this category,
>   use the AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers option.

Or try `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` which is like `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` but non-mixable by default.

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question. The goal is to only play music if other apps are not playing anything. This can be achieved by checking the shared `AVAudioSession`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
```

And only play your music if it returned `NO`. Note that since iOS 8.0, it is preferable to use another property (they have slightly different semantics):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint];
```

> The value is YES when another application with a non-mixable audio
>   session is playing audio.
>
> Applications should use this property as a hint to silence audio that
>   is secondary to the functionality of the application. For example, a
>   game using AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient can use this property to
>   decide to mute its soundtrack while leaving its sound effects unmuted.

You should also subscribe to `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` notifications and stop/start your music to reflect changes in `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint`.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
// stat/stop music based on AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint
}
```

Comment: that kinda works, but the goal is that the user can listen to their own tunes while playing the games.  Both of those sessions not do that.

Comment: Wait, so you want your apps audio to be mixed with other apps audio? Because then you need to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient `.

Comment: No.  I want all my sound to be muted.  Basically if they have music playing I want my app to be silent.

Comment: However if they don't have sound playing then I want to use my games music.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I subscribe to the AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudio?

Comment: I've added an example of how to subscribe to the said notification.